# Change window size via shortcut parameters

Tags: multiple-monitors, shortcuts, parameters

How can I change the starting size and location (on screen) of a program using only the shortcut dialog box, so that when I want to open a program at a certain size, on a certain screen?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the parameters would be as follows `--with "target location"` being the text between the quotation marks and shouldn't need to be modified`--  "target location" -height=1920 -width=1920` you can change the height and width to whatever you may desire. This is based off my general knowledge shell and programming.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan Is it possible to do this without static variables? I want to start a program with the height and half the width of my current window.